# Can anyone change the <input> amount value?

Tags: html

On my website, I have a checkout page where- once customers have entered their card details - they simply click 'Pay Now'. It is NOT a Paypal button.

I do not charge until I've confirmed their order, it takes just a click to accept their order.

My question is: Can they simply change the input tag and set the value to 0 to pay nothing?

Please have a look at this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="total-cost-val" value="3.85">
<input name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrder" value="Pay now" class="place-order" type="submit">    
<input name="_D:/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrder" value=" " type="hidden">
<input name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.formName" value="paymentForm" type="hidden">
<input name="_D:/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.formName" value=" " type="hidden">
<input name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderSuccessURL" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="_D:/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderSuccessURL" value=" " type="hidden">
<input name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderErrorURL" value="" type="hidden">
<input name="_D:/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.commitOrderErrorURL" value=" " type="hidden">
<input id="jsEnableCheck" name="/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.jsCheckForCheckout" value="true" type="hidden">
<input name="_D:/atg/commerce/order/purchase/CommitOrderFormHandler.jsCheckForCheckout" value=" " type="hidden">
```

It's the first line which I'm worried about - I'm not a programmer and I didn't make this, I simply copied from Google Chrome's 'Inspect Element' feature.

Can they change `value = "3.85"` to `value = 0` using 'Edit as HTML'?

If so does that work?

Comment: Does it actually work?

Comment: What do you mean? As said before one can edit the box with a new value and send it to your server. Don't put any data like prices into a hidden field. Better you put the ID of the item and load the price from the DB

Comment: and yes... the question if it works depends on your validation

Comment: @bub, Assuming already validated the price from the DB, you have to do for example 100 different kind of buttons ? or how can I post to paypal the final price? even validated

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, anything running on on a client's computer can be hacked by the client - especially HTML.

One thing you could do instead would be to, on the server, create a guid (or some other identifier) for that transaction and have another input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="transaction-id" value="127819A3-C0FB-404F-BFF8-D4FA2C4240EA"/>
```

Then save off the information on the server, so if they modify that value, it's exceedingly unlikely they'll turn it into a valid transaction so they'd be stuck with the real amount.

Sidenote: if that's XHTML, you need the slash at the end of the tag:`<tag />`

Comment: As you said it is exceedingly unlikley but it still is.

Comment: Unlikely, as in 0.00000037% chance of two matching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In general, you need to be always prepared for the case when someone sends a post after modified your structure or not even using your structure.

This is why a validation should have 3 levels:

- client-side validation: this should be running in the browser as a Javascript code and should prevent invalid form submits from wasting your resources by making sure that only valid requests are sent to the server
- application-side validation: should be running on server-side and should do more-or-less the same thing as client-side validation, so you prevent invalid requests from being sent outside your forms by hackers
- deep validation: this level should be reached if and only if the request passed both previous levels and here you should run the db. checks

So, client-side validation would prevent your server from bothering with invalid requests sent by users. Application-side prevents your server from conducting deep analyses on evident hack attempts. Deep analysis is the final step of validation. If a request was worthy to reach this level and even passes it, then the request is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to change the form values before they are sent, yes.

To protect against it, simply check the transaction **on your server** before you enact it - confirm the amount is correct as well as whatever other details you've gathered, and only fulfill the order when you have explicit, trustable confirmation in hand that the payment has been made through whatever service you are using.

If the amount doesn't match your expectations for the service/product, or the payment doesn't go through, simply return an appropriate error to the user along with instructions etc. on what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

> Can they simply change the input tag and set the value to 0 to pay
>   nothing?

Yes, visitors to the site can change the HTML or send a POST/GET request to the form handler with the altered information.

In general, **information from a client should be treated as untrusted**. There should **always be server-side verification**.

Since you didn't program it yourself, you might want to try spoofing the information and checking if there is server-side verification. If there isn't, you should hire a new programmer.

Answer (score 0):

*Can they change 'value = "3.85"' to value = 0 using 'Edit as HTML'?*

Yes, I can (I usually do similar thing using firebug to know my saved password, by changing input type from 'password' -> 'text').

*If so does that work?*

Yes, it works. Because when I submit the form it only checks for the current input's value. It treats it just as getting a value from a memory location.

---

So,
Never believe me (client side). I can even submit Google form through Facebook if possible.